# How to access the iPhone and iPod library files to use audio?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an application in which I want to access the iPod and iPhone library files for accessing audios of the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [iPod Library Access Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Audio/Conceptual/iPodLibraryAccess_Guide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008765). Main class for access and control is called [MPMusicPlayerController](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMusicPlayerController_ClassReference/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: is it possible to use the same ipod library for iphone alse

Comment: Yes there is no difference between iPod Touch and iPhone as they use the same API

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have access to your music files and related information about them, then have a look at the [Media Player Framework Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MediaPlayer_Framework/_index.html).